# facebook api get long term token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know it is advised against but I want to get the long term access token using javascript from the client, I have the user ID, the secret app, and the short term access token so this should be simple, but I can't seem to get it right.
For the sake of argument, let us say that

```
Secret app ID =1;
user-ID = 2;
short term token = 3;
```

The api call is

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

To make it work with the javascript api it should look like this..

```
FB.api(GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token});
```

Now I want to store the array it returns so I should change it to this

```
 var longToken= FB.api(GET /oauth/access_token?  
            grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
            client_id={app-id}&
            client_secret={app-secret}&
            fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token});
```

Now I have to add in the values so...

```
 var longToken=FB.api(GET /oauth/access_token?  
        grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
        client_id=2&
        client_secret=1&
        fb_exchange_token=3);
```

So what am I doing wrong, thanks so much?

Comment: Post your exact code. Or if what is you posted is your actual code, that is not valid JavaScript at all.

Comment: That is my exact code, from what I understand when you call the facebook javascript API you can use the graph api calls?  

If you cannot how do you change a short term token into a long term token?

Comment: What errors/responses are you getting?